# How to iterate through database until it find a match

Tags: loop, wpdb, php

How can I loop through my Wordpress query, and check each posts if one meta_value of meta_key `user_ip_reservering` match the `$ipadres`

**Code**

```
$args = array(
      'post_type' => 'reserveringen',
    );

    $reservation_query = new WP_Query( $args );
     if ( $reservation_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
      <ul>
        <!-- the loop -->
        <?php while ( $reservation_query->have_posts() ) : $reservation_query->the_post(); ?>
          <li><?php

          $user_ip_db = getUserIP();
          $ipadres = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'user_ip_reservering', true);
          $datum_nieuwe_reservering = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'datum_nieuwe_reservering', true);

          echo $ipadres . ' - ' . $datum_nieuwe_reservering . '<br>';

        ?></li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <!-- end of the loop -->
      </ul>

      <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <?php else : ?>
      <?php echo 'Sorry, er zijn geen reserveringen <br>'; ?>
    <?php endif;
    ?> <!--END OF SHOW ALL CUSTOMERS SELECTION -->
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. In your code, you already get the value of meta field with key `user_ip_reservering`, so you can check it. What exactly your problem is? What are you trying to do?